# Flutter app - Unable to test on real device! Something wrong with the X-Code version

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, android-studio

When I try to run the app on my device from Android Studio, it ends up with the following error: (Please note development team IS SET in my profile)

```
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team
> with a  Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is
> selected by:   1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
>        open ios/Runner.xcworkspace   2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
>      in the project settings   3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
>      You may need to:
>          - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
>          - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
>          - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
>          - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app   4- Build or run your project again
> 
> For more information, please visit:  
> https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices
> 
> Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> 
> Error launching application on DMan.
```

I then open my iOS workspace, and check my 'Signing & Capabilities'. I have the following all set there:

[image]

I then tried with running the app on my phone via workspace itself, by pressing the play button on top -left. and I get the following error:

[image]

Then I restarted my computer as advised but the problem is still there.

I am using:
Android Studio: Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1
X-Code: 13.2.1
iOS version: 15.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 13.2.1 will not support iOS version above 15.2 that's the reason for this issue update the Xcode to latest version to use iOS 15.5

Comment: Thanks, this opens some can of worms for me. To get x-code 13.4 which targets ios 15.5 I need to update my OS, which does not seem to come as an option. stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Register your device on [Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/). Then you will be able to test it on your device.

if you have done that. then check this
Go to your Settings > General > Device Management.

[image: Device management]

[image: Trust “YOUR DEVELOPER NAME”.]

Comment: It is registered.

Comment: i think the issue is with Xcode and iOS compatibility

Comment: No, it is compatible.

Comment: @Damandroid just restart your iPhone. Sometimes it also works.

Comment: It surely is a compatibility issue. My MBP is 2013, so can't have the latest OS Monterey. So I can't go above x-code 13.2 which can only support up to 15.2 iOS devices. Unless I can find a way to downgrade my iOS to 15.2, I am stuck! Check: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/